# Codeblocks Project.exe stopped responding c++

Tags: c++, exe

I am working on a simple algorithm for the gcd of two numbers. I don't know why it crashes when I finished entering a and b.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, d, i, max;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    if (a<b)
    {
        max = b;
    }
    else
    {
        max = a;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0)
        {
            d = i;
        }
    }
    cout << d << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a great time to [learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug small programs.

Comment: oh okay, I'm sorry for posting such a bad question.

Comment: `a%i` when `i` is 0 is your problem

Comment: @RichardCritten So, make it an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

problem is :  `a%i == 0 && b%i == 0` when i=0 . this code works fine now :

#include
    #include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, d, i, max;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    if (a<b)
    {
        max = b;
    }
    else
    {
        max = a;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if (a%i == 0 && b%i == 0)
        {
            d = i;
        }
    }
    cout << d << endl;
}
```